# Can't get absolute div to center horizontally in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, centering, css-position

I'm trying to build a site with a fixed left sidebar of 220px and a fixed page filling the rest of the screen. I'm attempting to fill the page section with an image and have information over the top. The code works fine in Chrome and Firefox but can't get to work in IE.

Can anyone offer any suggestions for a better alternative I'd imagine without using absolute divs?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrap"> 
    <div id="sidebar"> 
        <div class="logo">
        <a id="logo"> <img src="LOGO.png"/></a> 
        </div>
    <ul class="navigation red" id="red">
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="page" style="padding:0 !important;">
    <img src="images/back.jpg" class="back" alt=""/>

    <div id="center">
        <div class="header">
        <center> <h3 class="page_title">Website Title</h3></center>
        </div>
        <!-- services -->
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="one_half first">
            <div class="column_content">
                <h4> Title</h4>
                <img src="images/2.png"/>
                <p> <small>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text . </small></p>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="one_half first">
            <div class="column_content">
                <h4> Title</h4>
                <img src="images/2.png"/>
                <p> <small>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text . </small></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="one_half first">
            <div class="column_content">
                <h4> Title</h4>
                <img src="images/2.png"/>
                <p> <small>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text . </small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="one_half first">
            <div class="column_content">
                <h4> Title</h4>
                <img src="images/2.png"/>
                <p> <small>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text . </small></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background:#FFF;
    font-size:14px;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div#wrap {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto!important
}
div#sidebar {
    width:220px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background: #FFF;
    border-right:1px solid #2e2f2f;
    position:fixed
}
div#page {
    height:100%;
    left:220px;
    right:0px;
    background: #FFF;
    position:absolute;
    padding:2% 5%;
}
div#center{
    margin:0 auto !important;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    z-index:1000;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.group {
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px !important;  
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    bottom: 20px !important;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    max-width:850px;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    display:inline-table;
}
.header {
    padding:0 20px 0 20px !important; 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    top: 8% !important;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    max-width:850px;
    margin-left:auto !important;
    margin-right:auto !important;
}
img.back{
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:1024px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.one_half {
    font-size: 17px;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Been trying to get my head round this for a while now and not making any progress any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

--- EDIT ---

Don't think I made clear it's the group and header divs i'm trying to center and which aren't in IE

Comment: @Ejay Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I meant that I assume your question was upvoted in the "review" tab. Nothing wrong with the question except it's missing `<html>`

Comment: actually just forget it  and accept my apology. I think I'm not thinking clear. Will remove comments in 2 mins :)

Comment: It's alright thanks for pointing it out, I hadn't noticed @Ejay

Comment: What's the image look like here? http://jsfiddle.net/4ynyj/

Comment: Sorry just realised I missed off a bit of CSS for one_half, I'll update it now @Dawson

Comment: Have any ideas? @Dawson

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't what you want, I'd need you to explain your requirements better.
http://jsfiddle.net/HhddF/

```
.back {
    background-color:#3D6AA2;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```